# Why does a mutable borrow of a closure through DerefMut not work?

Tags: rust, closures, dereference

I am trying to mutably borrow a mutable variable. `Deref` and `DerefMut` are implemented for `Foo`, but compilation fails:

```
use std::ops::{Deref, DerefMut};

struct Foo;

impl Deref for Foo {
    type Target = FnMut() + 'static;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

impl DerefMut for Foo {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Self::Target {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut t = Foo;
    t();
}
```

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow immutable borrowed content as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:20:5
   |
20 |     t();
   |     ^ cannot borrow as mutable
```

Newer versions of the compiler have an updated error message:

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow data in a dereference of `Foo` as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:20:5
   |
20 |     t();
   |     ^ cannot borrow as mutable
   |
   = help: trait `DerefMut` is required to modify through a dereference, but it is not implemented for `Foo`
```

Comment: `t.deref_mut()()` works. Interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [a known issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/26186) regarding how the function traits are inferred through `Deref`. As a workaround, you need to explicitly get a mutable reference by doing a mutable reborrow:

```
let mut t = Foo;
(&mut *t)();
```

or by calling `DerefMut::deref_mut`:

```
let mut t = Foo;
t.deref_mut()();
```

Comment: Given this is a work-around, I would really favour using a method-name. It makes finding the pattern more easily (search for `deref_mut()(`).